# Singleton pattern dependency injection in angular

Tags: javascript, angular

As we know when we build a service in angular with a decorator `@Injectable()` and resolve it using the root injector , a single instance of the service will be created using Singleton.

If an application is deployed to server and assume two users have opened pageA which inturn calls ServiceA.

If we have a method

```
LoadSymbol() : void
{
 //Implementation
}
```

and if UserA calls LoadSymbol() will the loading symbol shows up in the screen of UserB also since we are using same instance of the class?

Answer (score 0):

No, That should not be the case as UserA and UserB are running different instances of the web application. Each has their owner browser which runs the angular code. therefore each will have their own instance of that class.

However, since its a singleton. Each user will only have  one instance of that class.